# How to display special and hidden characters from any file to cout using stream?

Tags: c++

So I want to be able to cout ALL the characters (hidden, special, Greek, and other characters) from any file into a text file. I've tried using `getline()` and `get()` functions but:

```
...
ifstream aFile("whateverTextFile.txt"); // can be any type of file besides txt file
char ch;
while (aFile.get(ch)) cout << ch;
...
```

also isn't doing the job. Want to read this "123abc@#$   " to cout "123abc@#$αβλ".

Comment: how do you want it to display characters that aren't printable? with a \ and a character? A hex code? what do you want?

Comment: If there's a degree symbol or alpha symbol or etc., I want to be able to see those symbols display as would a character on the console.

Comment: A file that contains "stuff/data/hidden/special/whatever" isn't a text file.  Trying to process it as one is likely to fail in ways that depend on the data in the file, how you process it, and likely other factors.

Comment: It's not just text files but other (or any) types of files too.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you mean by 'display', or 'hidden' characters.  Assuming you want to display control characters in hex, you would do something like

```
if(std::isprint(c)) {
    std::cout << c;
} else {
    std::cout << "0x" << std::hex << c;
}
```

Comment: If there's a degree symbol or alpha symbol or etc., I want to be able to see those symbols display as well. Is hex the best option to ASCII-compatible character encoding?